# NameError: name 'BookAdmin' is not defined - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and Python 3.6 I had this Error: NameError: name 'BookAdmin' is not defined and

this my code (models.py) in 'store' app.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Book(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     description = models.TextField()   
     publish_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

and in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Book

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author')

    admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

And the Error is

```
    File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\venv\bookstore\store\admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  File "C:\venv\bookstore\store\admin.py", line 8, in BookAdmin
    admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
NameError: name 'BookAdmin' is not defined
```

Comment: Did the below answer worked for your case?

Answer (score 5):

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author')

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Register your admin outside of your class definition. Not inside it!

Or do this:

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author')
```